# Exclude feature in CMake's configure

Tags: configuration, cmake, autotools

With autotool's configure every feature can be explicitly enabled by `--with-feature=...` / `--enable-feature=...` or explicitly disabled by `--without-feature` / `--disable-feature`.

Some CMake find packages scripts evaluate variables`feature_ROOT` to search there first, but it is [uncommon](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake-developers/2014-June/010766.html) and [discouraged](http://public.kitware.com/pipermail/cmake-developers/2014-June/010764.html). CMake evaluates several paths and tries to find the libraries there. To add a feature that is not located in the default paths, the right path can be added.

How can a feature be disabled, that is installed on the system and thus is found by CMake's configure? For example Java is installed in the default below `/usr` and found by CMake without adding the path for CMake; how can I disable Java? It will always be found.

I don't want to manually modify the CMakeCache.txt.

To sum up: I have a project that I don't want/can modify, it has a `find_package` and I have the package (e.g. Java) installed but I don't want CMake to use this package. I want a switch/flag do deactivate the installed and usually found package.

Comment: There are a lot of sub-options for command [find_package](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/command/find_package.html?highlight=find_package). For instance if you set `NO_DEFAULT_PATH` then searching in standard locations will be disabled. `how can I disable Java?` From [documentation](http://www.cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/module/FindJava.html?highlight=findjava): `The caller may set variable JAVA_HOME to specify a Java installation prefix explicitly.`

Comment: `but it is uncommon and discouraged` Well, I can't agree with developers here) I don't see what is bad if you will have more options to specify package location. In this case you can patch default `Find*.cmake` modules and place it in your repository. Then add 'em to `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` and use.

Comment: To clarify: I want to disable a feature from a user's perspective e.g. to disable a broken Java installation. Modifing the source code is not an option.

Comment: So you have a project that you can't modify and that have a command `find_package(Java)` (and you don't want to install java)? I think there is no way out, you need to modify source code then.

Comment: @ruslo I updated my question to prevent a misunderstanding. The package is installed but I don't want to use it / I don't want that CMake finds the package.

Comment: Create you own `FindJava.cmake` file and add it to the `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH`. When command `find_package` will be called, it will load your version. How about that? :)

Comment: @ruslo That could work, but I'd have do that for a dozen of find modules. Probably there is no CMake way of achieving this. I'll ask the CMake guys on there mailinglist.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I discovered, it is not difficult at all. To prevent my feature from being found, I pass

```
-DFEATURE_FOUND=FALSE
```

to CMake and then it is not found, even when installed.

Or one can pass

```
-DCMAKE_DISABLE_FIND_PACKAGE_FEATURE=TRUE
```

to suppress the find module completely.